# Automatically setting custom attribute for users signing up with an Azure AD B2C user flow

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a requirement in my application where we have two types of users:

1. Customers - who sign up using Azure AD B2C's user flow.
2. Administrators - who are created via API, not using any user flow.

In Azure AD B2C, we need to store an "extension_role" property for users. I want to automatically set the "extension_role" property to "Customer" when users sign up through the user flow, without them having to select this option.

What is the best practice to achieve this requirement?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use custom policies to do this.

In "AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail", add:

```
<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_role" DefaultValue="Customer" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
```